# Entity Framework 4.1 Code First and an Oracle CLOB

Tags: c#, oracle, model-view-controller, ef-code-first, clob

Currently I have a code-first model like this:

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int SERIAL_NO { get; set; }
    public DateTime SUBMIT_DATE { get; set; }
    public string SYNOPSIS { get; set; }
    public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; } // This is really an Oracle CLOB in the DB
}
```

In the ticket controller, when the user clicks Submit, I have it select the max SERIAL_NO out of the database, like this:

```
var lastSerial = db.Tickets.Select(x => x.SERIAL_NO).Max();
```

It throws this error:

```
ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got NCLOB
```

Anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Actually, I think you're not fetching the entire entity, only the SERIAL_NO. Check the actual SQL sent to database (please update your question with it). Make sure SERIAL_NO is of type int in the database

Comment: That is the actual SQL sent to the database. It's Linq. If I remove the DESCRIPTION field from the code-first model, it doesn't break. You are correct in that I only want SERIAL_NO in this case but though I'm almost certain that it's breaking because the datatype of DESCRIPTION doesn't match that which is the database, I don't know how to either convert it or make it match.

Comment: I see. For some reason it tries to load the entity and fails. It shouldn't even try to do that with the code provided. By the way, why are you fetching the last serial during Submit? If you use this to increment and get the id of the new Ticket, then it's a bad practice, because It's going to lead to bugs when multiple users are adding Tickets simultanuously. You should use a `Sequence` and a `Trigger` instead.

Comment: Yes, I know. I simplified the code. What I'm really doing is creating a serial number like XXX-YYY-ZZZ-001, and it only retrieves the latest number associated with XXX-YYY-ZZZ when the user submits the ticket, i.e. it gets the latest ticket right before it saves the new one to the database.

Comment: As for it attempting to load the entity and failing, whether I get it not to load the entire entity on this line, I'll need to load it to save the data to the database anyway (two lines down it would fail anyway.)

Comment: What provider are you using? ODP.NET? DevArt? Can you add a new model generated from the database and see if it's auto-generated code differs form your (I mean the datatypes)?

Comment: ODP.NET. And sure, I'll have it generate a new model and see what it throws at me.

Comment: The auto-generated file identifies the column as a public global::System.String

Answer (score 2):

In the mapping of the colum

```
.HasColumnType("CLOB")
```

Answer (score 1):

The newest release of ODP.NET (at the time of writing this post) is 11.2.0.3

Unfortunately, this version doesn't yet support Code First (see [Oracle® Data Provider for .NET Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e18754/featLINQ.htm) for reference)

> Entity Framework 4.1 is supported. However, the Code First feature, that is part of Entity Framework 4.1, is not currently supported.

If you're willing to pay, [DevArt claims that their provider supports Code-First](http://www.devart.com/blogs/dotconnect/index.php/entity-framework-code-first-support-for-oracle-mysql-postgresql-and-sqlite.html). They offer free Trial so you could check it out.

Another option is to generate code using EDM Designer.

Comment: Although it does not technically support code-first, if you write the model and the database side-by-side and point the model to the connection string to the database, everything works as expected, except, unfortunately, the CLOB datatype... which I'm trying to find a workaround for. :-)

Comment: I guess that database-first auto-generated code would support clob's so maybe you could find the difference and copy some auto-generated code into your Clob-WorkAround-Utility Class. Seems like Oracle is still working on Code First and it's not supported because of the issues with more advanced features like using Clob.

Comment: But I don't think that this is a good idea. You'll soon find another feature that doesn't work...

Comment: If you really wanted to stay with CodeFirst, then You could use some older technology like ADO.NET Data Adapters to work with BLOB/CLOB columns, and use Entity Framework for all the rest. This would require supporting two different database access technologies - I would rather avoid that.

Comment: All my attributs are being created as NCLOB at DDL file, how i change that?

Comment: @Campinho Please elaborate - how does it relate do my answer? How did you define your attributes? Maybe you should start a new question?

Comment: @surfen Sry, if have another problem. Thnks

Answer (score 1):

The original problem (getting the ORA-00932 error) on the query is because you cannot use DISTINCT when the SELECT-list contains a field with a large (e. g. CLOB) datatype. Does your generated SQL contain a DISTINCT clause and return the DESCRIPTION field?

It figures, a CLOB can potentially contain GB's of data, returning only distinct columns of it could potentialy mean comparing GB's on each individual column with the GB's or all other columns in the result set.

I guess other aggregate functions will also fail (min, max), as well as using the CLOB column in an order by, for the same reason. Since this is an old question and the hint I gave usually solves the "head scratching" for most coders, I will not look up the relevant spots in the SQL reference. Those who need the details know where to look (or what to look for) now.

Answer (score 0):

On you Model, add  attribute  [StringLength(100)]